# Hibernate search exact match for strings with dashes

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'd like to do an exact search for entity field that has "xx-xx-xx" format.

The entity looks as follows:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
class Resource {

    @Field
    private String address; // has "xx-xx-xx" format
}
```

The query creation process is as follows:
    `queryBuilder.keyword().onFields("resource").matching(searchQuery).createQuery()`

Suppose I have two resources with the following addresses:

```
aa-bb-cc
cc-dd-ee
```

When I run a search query `"aa-bb-cc"` I expect that only the first resource will be returned, but instead, I have the search returns both resources.

What should I change to do and exact search by resource field?

Comment: maybe something like `.setMaxResults(1)` will work

Comment: @XtremeBaumer, this question is more related to indexing/analyzing problem. Refer to the answers below to get better insight.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable the default Analyzer for this field, so that it's treated as "exact" keywords:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
class Resource {

    @Field(analyze=Analyze.NO)
    private String address; // has "xx-xx-xx" format
}
```

Comment: Exactly. @ilya-zinkovich the reason your query was matching both results is that, due to analysis, values were being tokenized ('aa-bb-cc' was translated into three values: 'aa', 'bb' and 'cc'), so your query was being translated to something like " 'aa' OR 'bb' OR 'cc'", which obviously will match both entities (both contain 'cc'). In your case removing analysis (or at least tokenization) should do the trick.

Comment: great thanks. This is what I initially thought about, but I was afraid of other possible consequences of disabling the analyzer.